# How do I require the typescriptServices.d.ts in a Node.js app?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use the typescriptServices.d.ts and typescriptServices.js that from built\local after running `jake local`. I'm trying to use them in a Node.js app, but I'm getting confused how to require them.

#### 1: Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type.

[image]

#### 2: Duplicate identifier 'TypeScript'.

[image]

#### 3: Compiles & Runs, but missing IntelliSense

If I wrap the code in an `export function` it compiles and runs, but I have to comment out `var TypeScript = require('./typescriptServices');` in order for IntelliSense to work. Bug in IntelliSense?

[image]

#### 4: Use aliases as workaround

This restores IntelliSense in the function, but IntelliSense doesn't work when writing the import statement unless I comment out the require line.

[image]

Code is from [TypeScript: get syntax tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187928/typescript-get-syntax-tree).

Comment: A related issue you can vote on : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2078

Answer (score 3):

The typescript compiler api / or / language service is not readily consumable from node.js

You can how ever open it up yourself like someone already did for the Compiler API : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23956556

Comment: It could definitely be made easier. I did get it working, but had to jump through a couple of hoops to keep the `var TypeScript` and `TypeScript` namespace from conflicting. http://blog.ctaggart.com/2014/06/typescript-ast-from-nodejs.html